# How do I make a hairline outline of an image?

Tags: photo-editing

I am trying to convert the following image to a vector outline so I can cut it on a laser.

I use corel draw to print to our laser cutter. If the line is hairline then corel will cut out the item.

Normally I get everything as a autocad file so this is stumping me. I really do not want to try and trace this.

[image: Photo]

Comment: Many image editing programs will have an edge-detection filter. Its a long time since I used Corel Draw but I am sure it had (or came with) a tool to automatically trace outlines from bitmap images

Comment: Does [Click `Bitmap` menu ⇒ `Trace Bitmap` ⇒ `Detailed Logo`](http://www.corel.com/content/pdf/cgsx3/tutorials/dr_4.pdf) not work with this image?

Comment: This short guide might help: https://melab.wikischolars.columbia.edu/file/view/How+to+Create+Hairline+Outline+in+Corel+Draw+for+the+Laser+Cutter.pdf

Comment: @PhilipAllgaier That worked enough to figure the rest out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you had AutoCAD. Within Autocad, you can import an image, put it as a background image and then trace over top. There might be an auto detect feature in AutoCAD too if I am not mistaken.